# gnuplot: min and max values for arbitrary number of columns

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to plot an arbitrary number of lines in a same plot. My data file is like the following:

```
1  10  15  20
2  20  25  30
3  30  35  40
4  40  45  50
5  50  55  60
```

I'm using multiplot to do this:

```
set multiplot
do for [i=1:ny] {
       plot 'data.dat' u 1:i+1 with lines lc i title word(names,i)
}
unset multiplot
```

where `ny=3` in this example. As expected, the yrange of each plot is different, so the graph looks very messy. I'm trying to add

```
set yrange [ymin:ymax]
```

where `ymin=min(col2,col3,col4,...,coln)` is the minimum value among all the columns 2-n and `ymax` is the maximum value. However, I still don't know how to get `ymin` and `ymax`. The function `stats` allow me to get minimums and maximums for one or two columns at the same time, but no more. Even if I do this column by column, I still don't know how to get the maximum among n scalars.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, multiplot isn't for drawing multiple plots in one graph, but to draw several beneath each other. I guess you want to iterate inside the `plot` command:

```
plot for [i=1:ny] 'data.dat' u 1:i+1 with lines lc i title word(names, i)
```

This uses ranges which cover the values of all sub-plots. And it gets the key right.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was actually looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use if statement, here is the code:

```
ymin=1000 #set ymin to a very large value
ymax=0    #set ymax to a very small value
do for [i=1:ny] {
stats "data.dat" u i+1
if (STATS_min < ymin) {ymin=STATS_min}
if (STATS_max > ymax) {ymax=STATS_max}
}
```